# Acrostic, not quite, but I'm found in a similar manner in this riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Since this is the first time I've had two puzzles not completely solved in a week, this puzzle was designed to be simpler.

> Very important, are the lines that I write,
> Certain words, they won't appear quite right.
>
> Harmony accompanies me, to those who listen,
> Poised elegantly, by those who have written.
>
> Bibles and songs hold me within their pages,
> I've appeared everywhere, throughout the ages.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must be

> Verse

Very important, are the lines that I write,

> A verse is a group of lines that form a unit in a poem or song

Certain words, they won't appear quite right.

> Usually to fit a rhyme or structure, words need to be moved around.

Harmony accompanies me, to those who listen,

> Verse writing is usually arranged in a metrical rhythm and usually ha a rhyme scheme which is favourable for musical arrangement.

Poised elegantly, by those who have written.

> Verses are intentionally written with such structure.

Bibles and songs hold me within their pages,

> Each of the short numbered divisions of a chapter in the Bible is a Bible verse, songs are often divided into verses

I've appeared everywhere, throughout the ages.

> Writing in verse is quite common.

Additional hint

> Taking the first letter of the first line, the second of the second line,... and the fifth of the fifth line spells out VERSE

Comment: For the last hint, did the title help you solve that?

Comment: Yes, it did, it made me search a few different places for a possible word.

Comment: Great job, this is correct. Just as a hint, this method be useful in solving my two other unsolved riddles.